# Does Laravel have any built-in feature for raising a permission error?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Right now when a user tries saving/editing something they shouldn't (perhaps by hacking a form to submit certain data), I abort with a 403:

```
public function store() {
    $data = $_POST;

    if(!array_key_exists('company_id',$data)) {
        $data['company_id'] = Auth::user()->company_id;
    }

    if(!(Auth::user()->hasRole('super') || $data['company_id'] == Auth::user()->company_id)) App::abort(403,"Cannot edit customers that do not belong to your company");
    ...
```

There isn't some kind of exception I can throw instead, is there? I don't like hardcoding "403" everywhere, and I'm not sure that's the best thing to do.

I think I'd like to kick the user to some kind of error page that scolds them for their bad behaviour and logs the hack attempt somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would typically do this with a route filter.  This makes it check if the auth is passed before it even reaches the route.  You would add something like the following to the application/routes.php file:

```
Route::filter('company', function()
{
  if(!(Auth::user()->hasRole('super') 
       || Input::get('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
          == Auth::user()->company_id)) {
     //do stuff to log that this happened
     return Redirect::to('your_error_page');
  }
});

Route::any('store', array('before' => 'company', function()
{
   //this would be your function "store"
   return View::make('store');
});
```

So, what this does is say for your store route, before we run it, we first make sure it passes the "company" filter - which checks if they have the role "super" or if the submitted company_id is equal to the user's company id (or if they didn't submit a company_id, we are defaulting it to the user's company id, in which case we know it will pass).

If it doesn't pass the filter, we log that this happened in whatever way you want, and then redirect them to an error page.

But now, anytime you want to make sure the company_id condition is met, you can just add "company" to the "before" portion of the route.